# could not connect to server: No route to host Is the server running on host "************" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: database, connection

My server and DB is running on Ubuntu Server (DigitalOcean), but I cannot connect to the external network.

I set up the "pg_hba.conf" and "postgresql.conf" files but still cannot connect.
I also opened the port 5432/tcp on the firewall but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This, open default port for postegresql work :

*firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5432/tcp --permanent*